# vue 3 input ref binding with validation, how should I prevent user's wrong value being updated

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to prevent user typing in "wrong" value
I till now thought I knew everything about `v-model` binding, but for this case, I feel so lost.

[Vue SFC playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to your question:

1. Why does the `<input />`'s visible value change when using `.prevent`?
   I don't know the answer, you'll need to dig into Vue's source code and figure out what's going on or, if that sounds too adventurous for you, you might chance a question on their discord channel.
2. How to make it work as intended?
   I'm guessing *"prevent user typing in "wrong" value"* means: the visible value on `<input />` should always be either `'a'` (a value which passes validation) or `'wrong'`.
   In order to achieve that, you have to force a change into `displayValue`'s `value` on every `@input`.

The problem is you are setting `displayValue`'s value to `'wrong'` on first *"wrong"* value and then, on the next *"wrong"* value you are setting it to `'wrong'` again. Why is it a problem? Because there is no change, so `:value="displayValue"` does not actually run. It only runs when there's a change in `displayValue`'s `value`.

Here's how to force a change:

```js
function withValidate(e: Event) {
  const newVal = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value

  displayValue.value = null
/*  
   this forces a change to `displayValue` even when there's no actual change 
   e.g: from 'wrong' to 'wrong'
 */
                  //  this allows input to be cleared
  if (newVal === 'a' || !newVal) {
    displayValue.value = newVal
    modelValue.value = newVal
  }
  else {
    displayValue.value = 'wrong'
  }
}
```

Now the `<input />`'s `value` will always get updated after a user `@input`.

Here's the updated [Vue SFC playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).